# jQuery selected = selected

Tags: jquery

I have `<select name="users"> ... </select>` in file **chat_select.php**.
I refresh this every 8 sekunds to **#chatSelect**.

This is a refreshing in file **chat.php**:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
   function () {

     $('#chatSelect').load('php/refresh/chat_select.php?hodnota='+$('select.user option:selected').val()).fadeIn();

  }, 8000);
```

What is wrong? I need that if I choose some value from select that it will be stay (selected=selected).

And what about this?: `$("#user option[value=" + val + "]").attr("selected", "selected");`

Answer (score 1):

Selected is a property: `$('my_select').prop('selected')` will set the property "selected" to true.

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: FYI you may have to add a true flag: `$('my_select').prop('selected',true);` to force JQuery to apply the property.

Comment: as of 1.6.1 you can also use attr like prop

Answer (score 1):

Save the state of the select box on change by doing

```
$('#YourSelectBox').change(function() {
    var x = this.value;
    $(this).data('saved', x);
})
```

Then to retrieve the saved state by doing

```
$('#YourSelectBox').data('saved')
```

Note: refreshing the page will clear any data you have saved.

Answer (score 0):

before each refresh, save the current selected option in a variable, and after refresh is done, use jquery to reselect it